# Formula or code to build list of results from input columns and templates

Tags: arrays, list

please can you help me write a formula or code for Google Sheets which will create a list of results based on several lists of list of inputs, and a list of build templates. I would like to have every possible combination and ignore any input rows which are blank. Here is an example of the inputs, the template and the expected results. With the first row as the column header:

Here is an example of the input columns, templates and expected results:

[image: example]

I have tried various array formulas, but I do not get the full output of all combinations

Comment: You need to store the lists as [JSON](https://www.spiceworks.com/tech/devops/articles/what-is-json/), [output](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array-of-json-objects-using-javascript/) to [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/).  Then use [handlebars](https://github.com/handlebars-lang/handlebars.js) templates & [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) to HTML. In, sort of, that order. ;-)  [Here's an example](https://github.com/jaycrav3ns/misc_scripts/raw/main/JS/json2html.zip)

Answer (score 0):

As a programmer, I would suggest using nested for loops to solve this:
one loop for every column so that when every loop is done (and since they are nested), you'll end up with the complete set of all possible unique combinations.

Below are examples in C and python, but the concept is universal. It doesn't matter in which language you code it, any language with loops will do.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-loops-in-c-with-examples/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-nested-loops/